# Address Windowing Extension

Tags: c++, winapi, memory, 32-bit, awe

I have an 32bit application with very large memory requirements.

I noticed that there is something called [Address Windowing Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

However I haven't found much information in regards to how to use it and also what disadvantages and problems one might run into while using this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It shouldn't work on versions of Windows at 64bits (read here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778.aspx Intel and AMD's specification of PAE does support the x86-64 architecture but the software layer of Microsoft's PAE (the API), called AWE, is not supported on 64 bit editions of Windows, so Windows Vista 64 bit cannot attribute more than 4 GiB of RAM for a 32 bit application.).
- Even on Windows 32 bits there is a "license" limit on the amount of memory usable (same page shows all the limits).
- And clearly it's complex to program :-) It's like using EMS on the old 8086.

Comment: Ah, no 64 bit OS support is a deal-breaker for me.

Comment: If you truly need much memory, you should try to convert the program to 64 bits (but it can be complex, especially if it needs to support "legacy" libraries)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm dependent on third party components that are in 32 bits.

Comment: Time to ditch those dependencies. You need to move to 64 bit.

Comment: The "license limits" flat out exclude AWE on Vista and Windows 7. Windows 2008R2 doesn't even have a 32 bits version, so AWE flat out isn't available on the last 3 Windows versions.

Comment: @MSalters "license limits" are about memory, and they are 4gb. You can still use 2gb more than without AWE.

Comment: If you can move your 32 bit dependecies out-of-proc that would allow you to move to 64 bit easily. At least easier that having to deal with AWE.

Comment: This answer is actually wrong, you can use AWE in a 32 bits app running inside a 64bit OS (that SQL Server does).

Comment: AWE only uses PAE on 32-bit Windows. On 64-bit Windows, the AWE APIs are still there, but they have a different implementation which does not rely on PAE. Technically, you can even use the AWE APIs from 64-bit apps–I struggle to think of any situation in which doing that would make sense, but technically it works.

Answer (score 0):

Well the truth is that you can use AWE from a 32bits application running inside a Windows OS 64bit, and you don't need PAE. For example MS SQL Server (before 2012 version) can be configured in this mode.

But unless you have a very specific requirements, probably is far a better option to port to 64bits.

You have several disvantages:

- Need to run with a user with `SeLockMemoryPrivilege`
- The memory can not be shared with other process. It is allocated in physical memory. Leaving less memory to the OS and other applications (with `AllocateUserPhysicalPages`).
- You need a virtual address in order to access such memory. So you can have a memory windows of 4GiB with `LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE` flag.
- If you want to access more thant 4GiB you have to map/unmap those physical pages (with `MapUserPhysicalPages`).

This [article](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/1099/win32/win321099.aspx) from 1999 explain how to use such API.